# Restangular fails with generating the URL when trying to GET/PUT

Tags: django-rest-framework, restangular

I have some problems with Restangular and getting/putting elements.
First if I try to get one element I receive error with cross origins.

```
Restangular.one('api/label-resource', 1).get().then(function(success) {
   // Change some propertries
   success.put();
}

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/template/1. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:3000/api/label-resource/1/', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

If I try to get it with the url the PUT fails because is trying to reach `http://localhost/api/label-resource/1/1/`

```
Restangular.oneUrl('api/label-resource/1/').get().then(function(success) {
    // Change some properties
    success.put();
}
```

My REST API is django-rest-framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first problem with cross-origins because of the missing slash I found that Restangular has a method for this - **setRequestSuffix('/')** but this is setting it globally not only for the current request.

About the second problem with generating bad url I found that I have to assign response to a local var and then make put requests on it.
Restangular.oneUrl('api/label-resource/1/').get().then(function(success) {
    var label = success;

```
// Change some properties
label.text = "New text";
label.put();
```

}